# Swashbuckle for custom model binder

Tags: model-binding, asp.net-core-2.1, swashbuckle

In WebAPI (.net core 2.1) I've got a URL query string that has the format of &title=fred&author=blogs&sort=-title (etc.). I'm trying out various ways of model binding this into a single "facets" dictionary of , e.g "title","fred" etc. The most flexible to is use a custom model binder.

However when I use Swashbuckle the swagger UI shows a parameter of 'request' that takes a type object. I can enter my raw querystring in here but then this gets sent on the URL as &request=title=fred&author=blogs.

Is there a way to tell Swashbuckle to not send the &request on the URL but to just send the raw contents?

Comment: did you use [FromQuery] in your controller method parameters?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No I didn't. In the end I reorganised my model to compensate best I could but I never got the same flexibility documented that my model binder would allow